# WPF: binding a static resource to a dependency property in a user control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, staticresource

I have a user control which is an icon container.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle"
           Width="{Binding SquareWidth}"
           Height="{Binding SquareWidth}"
           Fill="{Binding FillBrush}"
           DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding VisualItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasItemDependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(VisualItem), typeof(Canvas),
            typeof(SquareIcon), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public Canvas VisualItem
    {
        get => GetValue(CanvasItemDependencyProperty) as Canvas;
        set => SetValue(CanvasItemDependencyProperty, value);
    }
```

The icon drawings are defined as Canvas items in a resource dictionary:

```
<Canvas x:Key="appbar_3d_3ds" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
    <Path Width="32" Height="40" Canvas.Left="23" Canvas.Top="18" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 27,18L 23,26L 33,30L 24,38L 33,46L 23,50L 27,58L 45,58L 55,38L 45,18L 27,18 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

I instantiate my user control in the main form like this:

```
<controls:SquareIcon VisualItem="{StaticResource appbar_information_circle}" Width="16" Height="16" FillBrush="Black" SquareWidth="16" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
```

**But all I get is a transparent square.**

If I replace the "Binding VisualItem" by "StaticResource appbar_information_circle", the icon shows up.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did not follow mandatory naming conventions for dependency properties. The identifier field of a dependency property called `VisualItem` must be named `VisualItemProperty`, otherwise the XAML parser can't resolve it.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(VisualItem), typeof(Canvas), typeof(SquareIcon));

public Canvas VisualItem
{
    get => (Canvas)GetValue(VisualItemProperty)
    set => SetValue(VisualItemProperty, value);
}
```

It is not useful to use the `as` operator in the property getter, because the property value is always a Canvas. In case it's not (which is a programming error) wou'll want to get an InvalidCastException instead of a NullReferenceException.

You should also consider to change the type of your dependency property from Canvas to `Visual`. It would work the same way, but provide greater flexibility in terms of which elements could be assigned to the property.

---

As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Visual Binding is pointless. The Binding should just look like this:

```
<VisualBrush Visual="{Binding VisualItem}" .../>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly mistakes! Problem solved. I wasn't aware of this magical naming convention.